# Were all the verses of the Quran written down during the lifetime of the Prophet (s.a.w.)?

Tags: quran, prophet-muhammad, quranic-events

We know that during the lifetime of the Prophet (s.a.w.), scribes and other companions used to write down verses of the Quran. But by the time the Prophet (s.a.w.) died, did all the verses of the Quran exist in written form?

I was told that during the lifetime of the Prophet (s.a.w.), not all verses were written down. Only some verses were written down while other verses were only memorized.

Please provide sources/evidences for your answer.

Comment: "I was told that... " : "Please provide sources/evidences for your.." question!

Comment: I don't have any evidence. That's why I'm asking

Comment: Yes see for example in [is the qur'an really preserved or are there missing parts of the qur'an](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35426/is-the-quran-really-preserved-or-are-there-missing-parts-of-the-quran/35436#35436)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they were.

The Prophet chose the scibes and under his supervision they would copy word for word. Known scribes were: Ali ibn Abi Talib, Abdullah b. Masud, Abu Dardah, Zayd b. Thabit, Ma'adh b. Jabal and Salim Mawla Abi Hudayfah.

Ibn Nedeem (*Al-Fihrist, p. 41*) recorded 41 companions who had written the entire Qur'an with their own hands during the lifetime of the prophet.

In the Holy Qur'an there are many Verses which talk about the Qur'an as a book.

> It is (recorded) in those scripts (of the Preserved Tablet) that are
>   honoured, exalted, purified,  in the hands of those scribes  who are
>   honorable, righteous. (80:13-16)
>
> And they said, .(These are) the tales of the ancients he (the
>   messenger) has caused to be written, and they are read out to him at
>   morning and evening.(25:5)

Additionally , the famous hadith of the Prophet, about the two weighty things he would leave behind, says:"I leave among you two valuable things, the book of Allah and my progeny".

> The word `book' denotes existence of a collection and not of scattered
>   scribbles, nor of things which are in the memory but not written.
>   https://www.al-islam.org/the-collection-and-preservation-of-the-quran

Comment: But how do you know Al.Fihrist is authentic? Where does Ibn Nadeem get his source from? I couldn't find any hadith that says the entire Quran was written during the lifetime of the Prophet (s.a.w.).

Comment: And also, just because 'book' denotes existence of a collection does not mean that the whole Quran was in written form. Maybe Allah meant 'book' in a metaphorical way. As in, the Quran is in complete form with Him, but not with the humans.

Comment: Doesn't the Preserved Tablet refer to 'Lawh Al-Mahfuz' and not the Holy Quran?

Answer (score 0):

Salamou alaikoum,

Yes, because the first "aya" in the quran was :
"بسم الله الرحمان الرحيم إقرأ باسم ربك الذي خلق"
And the last "aya" was :
"بسم الله الرحمان الرحيم اليوم أكملت لكم دينكم و أتممت عليكم نعمتي و رضيت لكم الإسلام دينا "
And allah know the best.

Answer (score -2):

No they weren't written. Almost of all of the Quran was memorized by companions of Prophet(PBUH). When the number of companions started decreasing as they died in battles, during the caliphate of Usman(r.a), Usman (r.a) compiled the Holy Quran in written form as we see now.

Comment: @M. T Althua Where is your source?  How do you know they were not written down?