# Madani Quran vs Qaloon Quran

Tags: quran

Just found I've found another version of Quran readings called Qaroon Quran which have quite different Arabic readings like "marfiqaa" vs "mirfaqaa" (in Al-Kahf:16). Are they legit as well?

Comment: Qaroon or Qaloon? Your title and your message body don't match...

Comment: Qalun was after the sahaba maybe the third imam of the masjid nabawy in Medina. He mastered the qira'a of medina.

Answer (score 2):

There are a [number of readings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qira'at#The_Ten_Readers_and_their_Transmitters_2) of the Qur'an that are considered acceptable (see also: [What are the readings (qira'at) of Quran?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2676/22)); the [Qalun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qalun) reading is one of them although it is not particularly common compared to the Hafs reading (which is [pretty much universal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/13195/22)).