# Why are the number of verses different in Warsh and Hafs?

Tags: quran

In 57:24, there is a missing/added word in different Qiraats of the Quran as it says [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/64129/why-is-there-a-missing-added-word-in-quran-5724&ved=2ahUKEwisw4ug_fjtAhVLQUEAHXkeD1oQFjAAegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw0PJwdPgHkv5zuVi7s5NwZm&cshid=1609443790856).

But in Surah Baqarah, why are there 286 verses in Hafs version and 285 verses in Warsh version?

Comment: I think my answer on [How many verses are there in the qur'an](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5566/how-many-ayaths-are-there-in-al-quran) covers this. Be aware that this is not an issue of Warsh vs. Hafs, but of the verse count used. You could basically use the Kufi verse count in a Moshaf of riwayat Warsh and vice versa.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Thanks.. Is there any complete book where 7 Ahrufs, 10 Qiraats, all the missing/added words (like 57:24), and all the words of verses which contain differences in Ahrufs are explained in detail? –

Comment: There are many books about all the qira'at in fact there are 14 qira'at who at least have survived in literature. But the matter of ahruf is highly discussed in books on uloom al-Qur'an imam as-Suyuti has shown 48 different views on their definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a difference of how the verses are counted, not that there is a whole new sentence in one qira'a.

Specifically speaking, we normally consider (in Hafs 'an Aasim) الم to be the first verse of Surah Baqarah and ذَلِكَ الْكِتَابُ لَا رَيْبَ فِيهِ هُدًى لِلْمُتَّقِينَ to be the second. Warsh 'an Nafi (and some others), however, consider(s) these both to be one verse.

So, this is the first verse of Surah Baqarah to Warsh:

> الم ذَلِكَ الْكِتَابُ لَا رَيْبَ فِيهِ هُدًى لِلْمُتَّقِينَ

while these are two verses to Hafs.