# Who are the people that want Abu Darda to recite 92:3 as “And by him who created male and female”?

Tags: hadith-interpretation

Who is Abu Darda referring to in this Hadith

> Narrated Ibrahim: The companions of Abdullah came to Abu Darda, he looked for them and found them. Then he asked them, “Who among you can recite as Abdullah recites it?" They replied, "All of us." He asked, "Who among you knows it by heart?" They pointed at Alqama. Then he asked Alqama. "How did you hear Abdullah bin Masud reciting Surat Al-Lail?" Alqama recited: 'By the male and the female.' Abu Ad-Darda said, "I testify that I heard me Prophet reciting it likewise, but these people want me to recite it: ‘And by Him Who created male and female.' but by Allah, I will not follow them." 
>  **[ [Bukhari](https://quranx.com/Hadith/Bukhari/USC-MSA/Volume-6/Book-60/Hadith-468/) ]**

When he says

> These people

I thought it is Uthman and his followers because of the mention of Ibn Masud, who (as far as I know) opposed Uthmaan’s Qur’an, but I just wanted to make sure I am not misinterpreting the Hadith

Comment: This should have been addressed in [Qur'an 92:3 & Sahih al-Bukahri 4944](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/69097/quran-923-sahih-bukhari-4944). If you agree mark this post as a duplicate of your question.

Comment: @Medi1Saif yes 